# Installing jquery plugin

Tags: jquery

I'm a novice and I'm trying to create a carousel gallery on a website.

I've been trying to get owlcarousel to work for a while now. I've read numerous posts and how to's but I just don't understand what I'm doing wrong.

The website is http://www.vicandross.com/victoriaaustin

and the code is

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

<title>Victoria Austin</title>

<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="_ui/css/screen.css"></link>

<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="http://vicandross.com/_ui/images/vricon.png"></link>


<link rel="stylesheet" href="/owl-carousel/owl.carousel.css"></link>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="/owl-carousel/owl.theme.css"></link>

</head>

<body>

<div class="logo_row" style="background:#ffdacf;padding:0">
<div style="width:996px;text-align:center;margin:0 auto;background:#ffdacf;padding:20px 0">
<a href="/">
<img alt="victoria austin" src="http://www.vicandross.com/victoriaaustin/_ui/image/logo.png">    
</img>
</a>
</div>
</div>


<div id="owl-example" class="owl-carousel">
<div> <img src="http://www.vicandross.com/victoriaaustin/_ui/images/logo.png"></img></div>
<div> <img src="http://www.vicandross.com/victoriaaustin/_ui/images/cookies3.jpg"></img></div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1 /jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/owl-carousel/owl.carousel.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#owl-example").owlCarousel();
items: 1,
  loop: true,
  margin: 10,
  lazyLoad: true,
  merge: true, 
  video: true,
  responsive:{  
    480:{
      items:2
},

678:{
  items:3
},

960:{
  items:5
}
}
   });
</script>



</body>
</html>
```

I would really appreciate someones advice.

Thank you

Comment: On your website `/owl-carousel/owl.carousel.js` throws __404__. Please provide more details. Where is this file on your disk relatively to your script? Are you doing some rewrites on HTTP server?

Comment: @ElmoVanKielmo thanks, i was using the wrong folder name (no hyphen).

Comment: @DaveNewton  The file was at victoriaaustin/owlcarousel/ not /owlcarousel/ (the index file is in www.vicandross.com/victoriaaustin)and so I've fixed that. I've just looked at web console in firefox and it says: "TypeError: $(...).owlCarousel is not a function"

Comment: You're still looking for your files in the wrong location.  When you go to a page like vicandross.com/victoriaaustin and link to a file at victoriaaustin/somefile the link actually becomes vicandross.com/victoriaaustin/victoriaaustin/somefile.

Answer (score 1):

Exactly what the JS console is telling you; you have a malformed object around line 41-43:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#owl-example").owlCarousel();
    items: 1,
    loop: true,
```

You can't randomly start using object literal syntax in the middle of the source.

Did you mean to pass an object to the `owlCarousel()` method, e.g.,

```
$("#owl-example").owlCarousel({
    items: 1,
    loop: true,
    ... etc ...
});
```

---

Unrelated to the issue: when asking a question you need to provide actionable information, e.g., what happens, what's supposed to happen, info from the JS console (in cases like this where it's HTML/JS interaction), and so on.

Comment: Yeah, this would solve the problem if carousel js and CSS were reachable by thy browser...

Comment: @ElmoVanKielmo Yep, that also appears to be an issue :)

Comment: @DaveNewton Thanks for taking the time to offer. I'll take on board your advice about the kind of info I need to give when posting.

Comment: @DaveNewton What's supposed to happen: The plugin is for a scrolling gallery. The logo further down the page and the picture of the girl are objects in the carousel. If the plugin was working correctly they would be side by side and you would be able to move them. I hope that's the kind of thing you meant.

Comment: @DaveNewton with regards to passing objects etc., I was just trying to follow some of the guidance I found on the internet. For now I'm just interested in knowing that the plugin is correctly installed! Then I will start learning more about customisation. I hope that answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

Your looking for the plugins js and css files in the owl-carousel folder.  Your folder is actually named owlcarousel.  No hyphen.

Comment: That's an issue, but not the reason for the syntax error on page load.